# Removing Flutter ChipWidget with onDeleted property

Tags: flutter, get, arrow-functions

I am new to Flutter and I found below sample code from Google to demonstrate the declaration of a Chip widget with sync* and yield:

```
Iterable<Widget> get actorWidgets sync* {
     for (final Actor actor in _cast) {
      yield Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Chip(
             avatar: CircleAvatar(child: Text(actor.initials)),
             label: Text(actor.name),
             onDeleted: () {
              setState(() {
                 _cast.removeWhere((Actor entry) {
                   return entry.name == actor.name;
                 });
               });
             },
           ),
         );
       }
     }
```

My question may not relate to sync* and yield directly.

1. What is 'get' ?
2. How removeWhere() gets the parameter 'entry'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. get is the Getter, Every instance of the class has it and you can also modify according to your needs.
2. Here `Actor` is the class having various properties, where `name` is also one property. It must be imported or declared in the existing class from where it is being called.

That class should look something like this:

```
class Actor{
 String name;
 int age,
 // and many other properties

}
```

Here is this nice article for more: [Dart Getters and Setters](https://dev.to/newtonmunene_yg/dart-getters-and-setters-1c8f)

Comment: Thanks @Ketan.  But I am still having trouble to understand how removeWhere() gets the value from 'entry' (entry.name) while 'entry' has not been assigned with any value.

Comment: `entry' is a variable name to instantiate the Actor class. when we instantiate the class we assign it a variable name with which we can reference and use it, you can change 'entry' to any other letter and it will still work the same.

Comment: Thanks @Ketan.  I think I got the answer for my 2nd question.  By calling removeWhere(), it will trigger a loop to go through each element inside '_cast' (List<Actor>).  'entry' in this case is a temporary container for each Actor instance.